# Netbeans / PhpUnit: How do I enable TestDox in the GUI?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I have this very simple test. It just adds 2 numbers: …

```
#[DataProvider('additionProvider')]
#[TestDox('Adding $a to $b results in $expected')]
public function testAdd(int $expected, int $a, int $b)
{
    $this->assertSame($expected, $a + $b);
}

public static function additionProvider()
{
    return [
        'data set 1' => [0, 0, 0],
        'data set 2' => [2, 1, 1],
        'data set 3' => [1, 0, 1],
        'data set 4' => [4, 1, 3]
    ];
}
```

If I run my tests from the console with the `--testdox`-setting, the testdoxs from the `#[TestDox()]`-attribute are displayed:

> ✔ Adding 0 to 0 results in 0 
> ✔ Adding 0 to 1 results in 1 
> ✔ Adding 1 to 3 results in 4 
> ✔ Adding 1 to 1 results in 2

However, if I run the same test in the GUI, I only get the standard messages…

> ✔ testAdd with dataset "data set 2" (passed) 
> ✔ testAdd with dataset "data set 1" (passed) 
> ✔ testAdd with dataset "data set 3" (passed) 
> ✔ testAdd with dataset "data set 4" (passed)

This is the phpunit.xml. If I enter some crap here, the test fails in the GUI, so it is the correct file :D It has `testdox="true"`, but that seems to get ignored. How can I enable it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.2/phpunit.xsd"
     colors="true" executionOrder="random" failOnWarning="true" failOnRisky="true"
     failOnEmptyTestSuite="true" beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
     testdox="true" cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="display_errors" value="On"/>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1"/>
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Tests">
            <directory>_tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage/>
    <source>
        <include>
        </include>
    </source>
</phpunit>
```